# jquery ajax Socket error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Happy holidays everyone. I'm getting occasionally the following ajax error:

```
Object error java.net.SocketException: Unexpected end of file from server
```

I have no space in data I send and encode the data as well. I have timeout set to 5000. I wonder if there is anything else I could try for the Socket error. Much appreciate your time... Here is my ajax call:

```
getURL = function(data){
    var obj = null;    
    obj = $.ajax({
         async:false,
         type:"POST",                 
         url: url,
         data: data,
         timeout: requestTimeout
      })             
    .done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){            
        if(data){
            if(data.status_code != 200)
            {
                console.log("ERROR Status returned:", data.status_txt);
            }
            else
            {                    
                url_rsp = data.data.url;
            }
        }
    })
    .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ){
        console.log("ERROR:", jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);
     });    

    return obj;   
}
```

Comment: problem seems to be unrelated to your code, or caused by `data` which you haven't provided.

Comment: How are you getting Java errors in Javascript code?

Comment: Check your url, does it contain any spaces? is your content-length header set?

Comment: @Carcigenicate 500 errors are generally printed to the console, I would guess that is what is being sent from the server.

Comment: Did you try googling your error "Unexpected end of file from server" many other people have posted the same issue on StackOverflow.

Comment: @ Kevin B - from what I found on line so far, it appears to be a server or a network error. In Java, there are API to set SocketTimeout  - I want to see if something can be done with javascript.

Comment: @Sher Khan - my data has no spaces and it is a short string, but I'll check if I can reach content-length header with javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get around the error by forcing a second ajax post attempt after fail and that appears to cover most failed cases... The server is a 3rd party server, so I have no details on why the first post could fail.